# Unicode in database

Tags: sql, mariadb

Is there a way to convert a string or something like that to overpass the error `Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci, IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci, IMPLICIT) for operation '='`.

What I'm trying to do is to insert row in a table rows using rows from another DBB.

I'm using something like that `WHERE dbb1.table1.column1 = dbb2.table2.column2` (not exactly but then you understand) and column1 is `utf8_general_ci` and column2 is `utf8_unicode_ci`...

But I don't want to change it directly in the database, so is there a way to convert a column value inside the `WHERE` or something like that ?

Comment: Use `where binary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
WHERE binary dbb1.table1.column1 = binary dbb2.table2.column2
```